# Incorrect GPG keys when installing Foreman 1.16 on RHEL 7.4

Tags: rhel7, theforeman

As the title suggests, I'm trying to install Foreman 1.16 on RHEL 7.4

I'm using AWS with a t2.large instance (which satisfies the minimum 4GB RAM for to run the installer)

I'm following the [quickstart guide](https://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.16/index.html#2.1Installation) found in the official documentation

When I get to the stage where I need to run

```
sudo foreman-installer
```

I get the following error

```
Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install foreman-release-scl' returned 1: warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/foreman/packages/centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm is not installed


The GPG keys listed for the "Foreman 1.16" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.


Failing package is: centos-release-scl-rh-2-2.el7.centos.noarch
GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-foreman
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/execution.rb:285:in `execute'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider.rb:101:in `execute'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider/package/yum.rb:220:in `install'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type/package.rb:88:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Puppet>'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/property.rb:491:in `set'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/property.rb:568:in `sync'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction/resource_harness.rb:236:in `sync'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction/resource_harness.rb:134:in `sync_if_needed'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction/resource_harness.rb:80:in `perform_changes'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction/resource_harness.rb:21:in `evaluate'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:257:in `apply'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:277:in `eval_resource'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:181:in `call'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:181:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:517:in `block in thinmark'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:516:in `thinmark'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:181:in `block in evaluate'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/graph/relationship_graph.rb:121:in `traverse'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction.rb:171:in `evaluate'
/usr/share/gems/gems/kafo-2.0.1/modules/kafo_configure/lib/puppet/parser/functions/add_progress.rb:30:in `evaluate_with_trigger'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:238:in `block in apply'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/log.rb:156:in `with_destination'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/transaction/report.rb:144:in `as_logging_destination'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource/catalog.rb:237:in `apply'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:174:in `block in apply_catalog'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:232:in `block in benchmark'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:231:in `benchmark'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:173:in `apply_catalog'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:348:in `run_internal'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:224:in `block in run'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:65:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:260:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:198:in `run'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:354:in `apply_catalog'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in main'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:65:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:260:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:280:in `block in main'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:65:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:260:in `override'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:233:in `main'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/apply.rb:174:in `run_command'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:375:in `block in run'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:665:in `exit_on_fail'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:375:in `run'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:137:in `run'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:73:in `execute'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet:5:in `<main>'
/Stage[main]/Foreman::Repos::Extra/Package[foreman-release-scl]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install foreman-release-scl' returned 1: warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/foreman/packages/centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm is not installed


The GPG keys listed for the "Foreman 1.16" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.

Failing package is: centos-release-scl-rh-2-2.el7.centos.noarch
GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-foreman
Could not find a suitable provider for foreman_config_entry
Could not find a suitable provider for foreman_smartproxy
```

The below mentions disabling the GPG test (not sure if this is a good idea?)

https://community.theforeman.org/t/katello-3-5-rhel-7-4-install-failure/8291/3

Answer (score 0):

OK so managed to figure this one out (or my colleague did!).  Posting it here in case anyone else runs into this.

It's the same issue as referenced in this post:
https://projects.theforeman.org/issues/19600

The main difference is that we're behind a corporate proxy so had to manually create the GPG Key file

Copied the key from:
https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

Then uploaded to the server where I wanted to install Foreman, and ran:

```
rpm --import /tmp/gpg-key-filename
```

And everything worked fine!